# Что за ключевое слово такое в PHP?

Tags: php

Наткнулся в ходе изучения чужого кода на Yii2 с такой вот штукой

```
$countUsers = clone $users;
```

Что такое clone ? Нет я понимаю из название что оно клонирует, но как конкретно? Чем такая запись отличается от `$countUsers = $users`, как распределяется память.

Описания `clone` нет ни на php.net не на php.su

Спасибо.

Comment: Может плохо искали? http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все есть: (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php) (http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?php5_2). Подробное описание можно посмотреть по любой из этих ссылок